# Azure DevOps user story not being displayed in column 'ready'

Tags: azure-devops

So, a project that I am working on requires the custom column/silo of 'ready' to indicate that the initial analysis has been done and it ready to be picked up as a development object.  When I change the state of an user story to 'ready' it does not show in the appropriate column however when selecting another such as 'new' or 'active' it is displayed.  Is there a word restriction on the use of 'ready' as a column (silo)?

Comment: Did you configure that column to map to the "ready" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please make sure you have also configured the **state mapping** for your customized Ready column. Otherwise, if you change the state of work item it will not auto  show in the appropriate column.

[image]

More detail about this you could take a look at our official tutorial [Update Kanban column-to-State mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-columns?view=azure-devops#update-kanban-column-to-state-mappings)